# Restricting input with database relationships

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm having trouble getting my head around restricting input within a relational database. Heres the scenario:

Database: MySQL

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `manufacturers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `models` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `manufacturer_id`),
  INDEX `fk_models_manufacturers_idx` (`manufacturer_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_models_manufacturers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`)
    REFERENCES `manufacturers` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Table 3:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `model_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `photo` TEXT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(6,2) NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `manufacturer_id`, `model_id`),
  INDEX `fk_cars_models1_idx` (`model_id` ASC, `manufacturer_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cars_models1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`model_id` , `manufacturer_id`)
    REFERENCES `models` (`id` , `manufacturer_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I'm writing an application in PHP where someone can add a car to their database. As you can see, the car's model and manufacturer are linked from the Models table to keep cars linked by their model and manufacturers.
How can I ensure that when someone adds a car, they dont mix the model and manufacturer ID's up so they dont say model A is made by manufacturer C when its made by manufacturer B and it says to in the Models table.

Is there a way to do this with relations? Pretty sure there is just not sure on how to setup the tables correctly to prevent this.

EDIT: To clarify, only one manufacturer can make one model. If a manufacturer makes a car of the same model name it will be a new entry as it would have different specifications. This is a small db as i'll ad columns like specs later, just trying to get the base functionality working and to understand how mysql uses relations to restrict the input.

Comment: I would remove `manufacturer_id` from `cars`, since it's already in `models`. If you need to find a car's manufacturer, just do a join on `models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Car` table is having a combination of `model_id` and `manufacturer_id` as a primary key. Now when you add a new car, the manufacturer_id will act as a foreign key in the `manufacturer` table and `model_id` will act as a foreign key in the `model` table.

Hence there won't be any clashes as you say.
Also, `model` table has a many to one relationship with the `manufacturer` table with primary key as `id`.

It is a very open problem, you can find other ways to design your database, it actually depends on your needs and how you want to project your system.

Comment: I agree. A lot depends on the requirements. A small, two column table mapping brand in one and model in another is also possible.
Can the same model be built by two companies (Austin and Morris Mini)? Model names can clash (Riley and Nissan Pathfinder) so a user's search should not stop at one match..